# How to properly setup TravisCI For a simple C project

Tags: c, makefile, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup TravisCI to do automated build and tests for me on a C project.

For me to learn and understand it I made a sample github repo to make it work before moving it to my final project.

My [Project](https://github.com/Farving/AutomatedCBuildUsingTravisCI) consists of basically 3 files:

.travis.yml:

```
language: C
```

makefile:

```
hellomake: main.c
    gcc -o hellomake main.c -I.
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

As the project is now I get the following error in Travis:

```
0.00s$ ./configure && make && make test
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./configure: No such file or directory
The command "./configure && make && make test" exited with 127.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `./configure` is not required. Just run `make`

Comment: How do I specify that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [The Docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c/#Default-Test-Script) the default `script` for C projects is `./configure && make && make test`. However, as specified just a couple of lines below, "This can be overridden as described in the [general build configuration](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/) guide."

For example, for your project (which only has a `Makefile` without a `test` target) you could use:

```
script: make
```

For building it (append to `.travis.yml`).

Comment: So simple, yet I couldn't see it... What if I wanted to append a test? then script: make && make test?

Comment: @CarstenFarving Yes, either `script: make && make test` or something like [this](https://github.com/nabijaczleweli/Cpponfiguration/blob/master/.travis.yml#L33-L36) ([docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step))